Hide toolbar when viewing pdf in firefox using Pdfmake.js
Im using pdfmake to open a pdf using vue 3 js. Issue is that in firefox browser there is a toolbar visible which has option to edit. This should be prevented.
Using below code to open a pdf in new tab
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
